# Create a database from stored procedure depending on some condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Let I have a Test database where I keep a table `Employee` with these columns:

```
Id, EmpName, Status, EntryDate.
```

Now I want to create a stored procedure with following condition:

All status true employee rows of 2018 (`Entrydate`) will be in an archival database called `Employee_2018` (this database will be created using the stored procedure if it does not yet exist) and create a new table with the same structure as the `Employee` table. Then data will be inserted. At the same time, the archived data will be deleted from the primary database, so it only has tracking for the current year.

Please help me.

Comment: `Employee` is a table - but when you talk about `Employee_2018`, you're talking about an "archival **database**" - do you **really** mean database, or much rather just a table inside the current database?

Answer (score 1):

```
 Alter PRocedure SPCreateDB
 As
 Begin

 CREATE DATABASE Sales  
ON   
( NAME = Sales_dat,  
FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL 
Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\saledat.mdf',  
SIZE = 10,  
MAXSIZE = 50,  
FILEGROWTH = 5 )  
LOG ON  
( NAME = Sales_log,  
FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL 
Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\salelog.ldf',  
SIZE = 5MB,  
MAXSIZE = 25MB,  
FILEGROWTH = 5MB ) ;


IF (EXISTS (SELECT name 
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
WHERE ('[' + name + ']' = 'Sales' 
OR name = 'Sales')))
begin



Declare @SqlStr As varchar(2000)

set @SqlStr = 'CREATE TABLE Sales.dbo.tblEmployee ( EMPID bigint, EMPNAME 
Varchar(200), EMPMAILID Varchar(50) )'

Print (@SqlStr)
Exec (@SqlStr)
End

Else 

PRINT 'db not exists' 

END
--drop dataBAse Sales
```

Comment: Try the Above one Please try with your own Ldf and Mdf file Path.